# Why cant I set my layout weight in my linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a layout file as so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments_row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:weightSum="2">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now in my code I programmatically Add 2 fragments to the LinearLayout named fragments_row1

However In the layout file of my fragment I cannot set the weight of the linear layout? I wish to have both fragments displayed aside one another in a 50% weight layout.

Here is the code for my two fragments layouts:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="IMAGE" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_image_imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Product Image"
    android:src="@drawable/call_waiter_icon" />
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Box" />
```

I want the equivalence of this but I need to add the fragments programmatically.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments_row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="dds.ImageFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dds_image" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:name="dds.RatingFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dds_rating" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments_row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

and the code to add the fragments

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame1, frag1, "fragment_grandchild1" + fragCount).commit();        
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame2, frag2, "fragment_grandchild2" + fragCount).commit();
```

Comment: Why not add `FrameLayout`s inside the main layout file where you want to put the fragments with the proper weights you want, then only assign the fragments to that `FramgeLayout`. Instead of `adding` the views, you are `assigning` the views.

Comment: @LuckyMe Just Tried and it still doesnt work.  here is what I did please see edit:  I get a big blank space where the two fragments are meant to be.

Comment: I just noticed something in your question, do you NEED the fragments to be added grammatically? Or is hard-coding the "portal" okay?

Comment: @LuckyMe Needs o be dynamic. I build my view with certain amount and layout of fragments bases on a JSON Object i receive from the server.

Comment: I thought about your design for a while, and it has two flaws, which I believe should be addressed before fixing this. You are manually creating a listview that will simply display all of the items, and in the case where there are many, it will take a lot of resources. You should implement the ListView with custom adapter. The second point is the fragments, you are using them to simply display an image and a text, and you will have `2*x` fragments where `x = # of rows` that is a lot and resource intensive. You don't need fragments here at all.